# Poll visible only for registered users

Tags: php, authentication

i am working on a simple site project just for testing things that i have learned but making a poll visible only for registered users is giving me a headache. I just can't make it disappear when the user is not logged in. Thanks for all the help!

```html
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbConfig.php';
$username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST")
{
 header('Location:mainpaige.php');
}
if(isset($username) && isset($password))
{
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'LIMIT 1");
 if(mysql_num_rows($q) == 1)
 {
  $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
  $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
  header('Location:mainpaige.php');
 }
 else
 {
  $_SESSION[error] = "Wrong name or password";
  header('Location:mainpaige.php');
 }
}

?>
```

this is my login.php for the login form. And this

```html
<?php 
session_start();
?>


<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="logical.css">
  <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = utf-8" />
  <title>Logical</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="back">
   <a href="../../mainpaige.php">Go Back</a>
  </div>
  <div class="centraltext">
   <h1>Top 10</h1>
  </div>
  
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
   {
  ?>
   <div class="poll">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.easypolls.net/ext/scripts/emPoll.js?p=59a6fa56e4b0f0b62d08adbe"></script>
    <a class="OPP-powered-by" href="http://trailguide.net/html" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <div style="font: 9px arial; color: gray;">bike trails</div></a>
   </div>
  <?php
   }
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

is the code with the poll div which i want to hide for not registered users, thanks!

Comment: You need to add more context, and some code. It'll help a lot, but for now it seems like the solution you're looking for is fairly simple. I'll leave an answer below.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for helping me i know this probably is a dummy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you need something that identifies whether the user is logged in, I'll give you a really simple example.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = PLACE_THE_USERID_HERE;
```

Then you can do a simple if statement to determine whether you want to show the poll or not.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != null) {
     //Place poll code here
}
```

This statement just checks if the user_id is set and if the user_id isn't null

This is very basic, and it will need some work. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to display html only for certain visitors, you can accomplish that in a number of ways. One way you can do it is when a user logs in (however you have that setup) you can set a $_SESSION variable to true, or some other value.

For example:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

Then in your html you can do something like:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']){ ?>

<!-- HTML GOES HERE -->

<?php } ?>
```